# .NET Core - EF - The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked

Tags: entity-framework

**I know there are already answers for this one, but none of them worked so far**

EF keeps returning the error :

```
The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked.
```

- although I disabled traking using QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking
- I tried **_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;**
- I also tried

```
    services.AddDbContext<SomeDBContext>(opt => 
        opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("***********"))
           .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
           .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
```

I cannot even figure which line produces the error

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> PostPartner(PartnerCreation partnerCreation)
{
       _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        _context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(1);

        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;

       if (user == null)
       {
            return NotFound();
       }
       else
       {
            partnerCreation.Partner.Id = partnerCreation.Partner.Id > -1 ? partnerCreation.Partner.Id : null;
            partnerCreation.Manager.Id = partnerCreation.Manager.Id > -1 ? partnerCreation.Manager.Id : null;
            partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.Id = partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.Id > -1? partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.Id : null;
            partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.PartnerId = partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.PartnerId > -1 ? partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.PartnerId : null;
            partnerCreation.Partner.ModificationUser = user;
            partnerCreation.Partner.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (ProductRetributionData data in partnerCreation.Partner.retributionPlan.ProductRetributionData)
            {
                 data.Id = null;
            }
            partnerCreation.Partner.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;

            _context.Partners.Add(partnerCreation.Partner);
            _context.Users.Add(partnerCreation.Manager);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return partnerCreation.Partner.Id;// CreatedAtAction("GetPartners", new { id = partner.Id }, partner);
     }
}
```

thanks for helping me on this

Answer (score 0):

The [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-add-1(-0)) method causes the provided entities to be set to the [Added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-entitystate-added) state. So removing the `user` from the ChangeTracker has little effect, as in `_context.Partners.Add(...)` it is added again. From then on, whenever another untracked `User` is added with the same id, it would cause the error. This could happen in `_context.Users.Add(...)`.

If you step through the code using the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#code-stepping) you should be able to identify the line causing the error.
See the [Change Tracking
docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/) for further information.